# CruiseControl.Net - inclusion of html report? (I get 'Unable to find file')

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have build that produces a (NCover 3.4 Summary) html report.

I'd like to configure the Dashboard to show the html report.

The report is produced perfectly in working folder during the build - my problem is referencing the report from the Dashboard. Should I do something to store it from working folder into the 'cc.net build records'? I don't really understand the inner workings there...

My use of plugin in the Dashboard.config is shown below. I don't know what I should use actionName for and have left it with value from documentation.

The link in CC.Net resolves as: http://DummyServerName/ccnet/server/local/project/DummyProject/build/log20101221100723Lbuild.2.0.0.176.xml/viewReport.aspx

Thanks for any comments,

Anders, Denmark

```
  <htmlReportPlugin description="NCover Summary" actionName="viewReport" htmlFileName="coverage_summary.html" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CCNET Documentation [1] :

> This plug-in can display any file that
>   is in the build folder under artefacts
>   folder for the project. It cannot
>   display files from any other location
>   (for security reasons). Files can be
>   published to a build folder using the
>   File Merge Task. This will
>   automatically generate the correct
>   folder structure for the HTML reports.

Either way, you can generate an xml report, merge it into the ccnet log and use an xsl to display it in the dashboard/emails.[2]

[1] http://build.nauck-it.de/doc/CCNET/HTML%20Report%20Plugin.html 
[2] http://docs.ncover.com/how-to/continuous-integration/cruisecontrol-net/

Comment: Thanks - but the links provide correct information about including xml-based reports, while my problem is the single report that's html-based. Is there a way that I can verify that the html file is indeed included in the individual build artifacts? Then at least I can see that I'm on track that far (The file is listed as a merge-file for the project).

Comment: I think the first link is about the html report plugin but you surely have already read it ;). Can you post your CCnet project configuration so that I can test it home. As for the build artifacts, did you set the action="Copy" part in your merge task? cf http://build.nauck-it.de/doc/CCNET/File%20Merge%20Task.html

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but I had all but given up. It turned out I had written "copy" instead of "Copy"...